# VBA Excel: How to pass one parameter of different types to a function (or cast Int/String to Range)?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing some VBA functions in Excel that compute word values and cross sums of the input.

I'm passing the input as `Public Function cross_sum(myRange As Range) As Integer` to them so that they take cell references as input, e.g. `=cross_sum(A1)`. Works fine.

However when I try to chain two functions like `=cross_sum(word_value(A1))` I run into th VALUE error because `word_value()` returns an Integer value and not the Range `cross_sum()` is set to expect. However I did not find a way to cast an Integer (or String) into a Range.

As Excel's built-in functions support chaining as well as Range input I wonder how.
Unfortunately this is my first VBA project so I wonder if and how to cast or what type to choose to get this working both ways.

Any pointers appreciated!

TIA,
 JBQ

Comment: It would help to show the actual functions you're working with.  There's no way to cast an integer to a Range - they're fundamentally different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass  **Variant** to a function and the function can determine the *type* of input:

```
Public Function Inputs(v As Variant) As String
    If TypeName(v) = "Range" Then
        MsgBox "you gave me a range"
    Else
        MsgBox "you gave me a string"
    End If
    Inputs = "done"
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    Dim st As String
    Dim rng As Range
    st = "A1"
    Set rng = Range(st)
    x = Inputs(st)
    x = Inputs(rng)
End Sub
```

Comment: I had seen the variant data type but the TypeName() function was the link I was missing. Now it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, it is hard to know what you could change. That being said...

There is not a way to convert an integer to a range. You would have to create a function to do so if that is what you desired.

You could create a converter function, maybe titled `IntegerToRange`, that takes an integer and after some logic (maybe 1 = "A1", 2 = "A2" or something), will return a range. Your cell formula would then be `=cross_sum(IntegerToRange(word_value(A1))`

Alternatively, you could modify your `word_value` function to return a range instead of an integer. Your cell formula would then be `=cross_sum(word_value(A1)`.